# Why this way is bad for use git?

Tags: git

I read on facebook group a post on git commit flow and the user ask this:

"I use this for commit my code"

```
git add . && git commit -m "commit message" && git push origin master
```

Some users commented on like that:

"This is the wrong way to use git" and more comments like that.

For my projects I use the same "flow", why is bad ? I can't find anything to exaplain why this is wrong.

Comment: If you're the only developer working on the repository, and if you want to commit everything in the current directory that has changed or has not yet been tracked, then it's probably Ok. If there are other team members, then this ignores possible changes by other developers.

Comment: The worst part is the `git add .`, or rather the use of `.` to select all files in the current directory and sub-directories. This will add all *untracked* files as well. Which might not always be a good idea. A possibly better way would be to use `git commit -a -m "..."` as it will only add already tracked files to the commit.

Comment: People are always going to tell you what they think is best. Just like people telling you that some programming language is best. Surely worth consideration, but in the end you should just do what you learn, and if you learn multiple ways to do something then choose what you like. I always say that unless someone is playing me to do it their way, I’ll do it my way.

Answer (score 5):

`git add .` adds/stages all of the files in the current directory. This is for convenience, and can still be used if you have certain files you don't want to add by using a .gitignore.
It is always a good practice to check `git status` after staging files for a commit to look for any unnecessary files which might have been staged. You might accidentally push the environment variables or maybe any undesired file without your knowledge thus polluting your codebase.